# Haskell Random Number Generator

Tags: haskell, random

I want to spawn an enemy at a random time in my game.
To do this I wanted to check each frame if a random value [0..100] == 50

```
spawnEnemy :: World -> World
spawnEnemy (world@World { rndGen = r, enemies = e }) = world { enemies = if rand 0 100 == 50 then Enemy (rand (-200) 200, rand (-200) 200) 0 0 : e else e }
    where
        rand :: Float -> Float -> Float
        rand l h = fst $ randomR (l, h) r
```

(here rndGen :: stdGen and enemies :: [Enemy])

But rand never seems to return 50.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You have a typo in your code. The `=` in `rand 0 100 = 50` should be `==`.

Comment: Are you ever stepping the rng?

Comment: A random Float between 0 and 100 will almost never be exactly 50. If you want (say) a 1% chance, you might check for `r <= 1` instead. Also, you throw away the new generator so your rand function will always return the same value.

Comment: To give you some idea, your enemies currently have about a one in a billion chance of spawning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The chance of getting a random Float to equal 50 is pretty low because Floats are not necessarily whole numbers. Try converting your random number to an Integral first using `floor`.